# Finding attributes on base type

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to implement an `ICodeIssueProvider` to detect if a class (or one of its base types) has a certain attribute or not.

```
public IEnumerable<CodeIssue> GetIssues(IDocument document,
        CommonSyntaxNode node,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var methodDeclaration = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)node;
        var semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModel(cancellationToken);

        var methodSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(methodDeclaration);
        var typeSymbol = methodSymbol.ContainingType;

        // The following only gets attributes declared on this class, how to
        // also include those declared on a base class ?
        var attributes = typeSymbol.GetAttributes();
```

Is there a better way than walking up `typeSymbol.BaseType` all the way to `System.Object` and calling `GetAttributes()` on the way?

Also, is there a better way to check if a `typeSymbol` derives from a specific class than walking up `.BaseType` and checking manually

(And yes, there is a reason not apparent from the sample below for checking `MethodDeclarationSyntax` nodes and not `ClassDeclarationSyntax` nodes)

Answer (score 1):

**tldr;** No, there is no single method call to do this (as of Sept 2012 CTP Roslyn).

The parent classes you need to search may be (and usually is) a completely separate Syntax Tree to the class you are in. If all your classes were within a single `namespace` declaration (shudder) then you could search from that `SyntaxNode` root.

Chances are, your classes are one-per-file, so although they share the same namespace, they're not under the same Syntax Tree root.

Roslyn causes much head-scratching because the Syntax Trees are more akin to the layout of the code files rather than the types the code represents.

There might be a way of creating a new Syntax Tree (existing Syntax Trees are immutable) out of all the classes that exist under that `namsepace` and then search that tree. To me, that feel like way more complexity than needed, especially as a walking-up-parents method is far more maintainable.

Comment: What about this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.isymbol.getattributes?view=roslyn-dotnet